# Distance Matrix Service on c#

Tags: c#, web-services, google-maps-api-3

How can I use the distance matrix service through c#?

or where can I get the wsdl file to upload it to soap?

The only way is their examples presented in js..

Distance Matrix WebSite:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems the service is REST based, so the simplest is to use a WebClient to download the contents:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Vancouver+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false");
```

Now you got a Stream containing the XML results.

You could use a XmlSerializer to decode the XML into code, or maybe use XDocument.Load to load it into a XDocument which you can use some DOM traversing or XPath queries to fetch the data you want:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```